# Is soap_ssl_accept() function required in SSL implementation in gSOAP?

Tags: ssl, soap, openssl, ssl-certificate, gsoap

I am implementing SSL in a gSOAP-based application with the following scripts on the server and client side. But I am getting an error that `SSL_accept()` fails in `soap_ssl_accept()`.

gSOAP release: 2.8.123
OpenSSL version:

**Server implementation**

```
if (soap_ssl_server_context(&soap, 
    SOAP_SSL_DEFAULT, //Authenticate the client using TLS v1 to 1.3
    "/home/xxx/CA/server.pem", //private key
    "xxxx", //password to read server.pem
    NULL, //CA file certificate to verify client
    "/home/xxxx/CA/cacert.pem", //CA path to verify client
    NULL, //RSA used for key exchange
    NULL, //seed the PRNG using the specified file with random data
    NULL //identification for SSL session caching to speed up TLS
    )) 
    {
     soap_print_fault(&soap, stderr);
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Then I initialised SSL with `soap_ssl_init();` in the main loop.

After initialization I call the `soap_ssl_accept(&soap)` function as follows

```
if (soap_ssl_accept(&soap)){
    soap_print_fault(&soap, stderr);
    fprintf(stderr, "SSL_accept error: %s\n", soap_faultstring(&soap));             
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);             
}
```

**Client implementation**

Initialisation and certificate verification callback

```
soap_ssl_init(); //Initialize the SSL/TLS library
  
   //Define certification verfification call back function
   int ssl_verify_callback_allow_self_signed_certificates(int ok, X509_STORE_CTX *store)
   {
     if(!ok && X509_STORE_CTX_get_error(store) == X509_V_ERR_SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN)
     {
       X509_STORE_CTX_set_error(store, X509_V_OK);
       ok = 1;
     }
     return ok;
   }
   
   soap.fsslverify = ssl_verify_callback_allow_self_signed_certificates;
```

Its context

```
if (soap_ssl_client_context(&soap, 
                               SOAP_SSL_DEFAULT | SOAP_SSL_SKIP_HOST_CHECK,
                               "/home/xxx/CA/client.pem",
                               "xxxx",
                               NULL,
                               "/home/xxx/CA/cacert.pem",
                               NULL
   ))
   {
     soap_print_fault(&soap, stderr);
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
```

Running this code code with `soap_ssl_accept()` function generates **SSL_ERROR_SSL: 0A00009C:SSL routines::http request** error.

With detail: `SSL_accept()` failed in `soap_ssl_accept()`

I commented the `soap_ssl_accept()` function, and the code works fine. According to the [documentation](https://www.genivia.com/doc/guide/html/group__group__ssl.html#ga990083effa5d8ed931fd75dc2630a2cc) this function should be called to perform the SSL/TLS handshake with a connected client. This function enforces HTTPS connections that are initialised with `soap_ssl_server_context`.

Would SSL implementation be complete without it? If not, how can I make it work?

Comment: A `soap_ssl_accept()` call is required to implement a TLS/SSL server. If you don't use it, then the server responds to plain HTTP only. So it may appear to work, but it is not secure. The fact that `soap_ssl_accept()` returns "http request" error means that it received a plain HTTP request that should not be processed.